# How to convert a Variable in Oracle to date type using TO_DATE

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date-formatting

i get the input from java to oracle

```
custom_date_in IN Table1.custom_date%TYPE,
```

the input is 2015-07-11 which will stored in custom_date_in

i want insert the input into the table which the column type are Date type

i tried to use the follow sql but fail,

INSERT INTO Table1 (custom_date) SELECT TO_DATE(custom_date_in,'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM TABLE

The following are the error message i get

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: Check the type of `T_MT_APP_DATE.custom_date%TYPE`, I thing it is not a VARCHAR2 and therefore you get the problem.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Ok, done.

Answer (score 2):

> custom_date_in IN T_MT_APP_DATE.custom_date%TYPE,

The **IN** parameter is already a **DATE** data type, why would you convert a date into a date? You need **TO_DATE** to convert a date literal into date.

So, just assign the date value to the variable:

```
custom_date := custom_date_in;
```

Also, you have a missing **colon** while assigning the value. Keep in mind, in **PL/SQL** you need to use `:=` instead of `=`.

Alternatively, you could pass the date value as a string `2015-07-11` i.e. **VARCHAR2**, and then apply `TO_DATE(custom_date_in,'YYYY-MM-DD')` or the **ANSI** date literal `DATE '2015-07-11'`.

Comment: the value i send in is not DATE, at Java i send in the value as String then i want to store that String into DATE type in database.

Comment: @Jack What is the datatype of `T_MT_APP_DATE.custom_date`?